# added constraints but forgot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added `constraints` but now i want to check the history what change was made and when was made, i am so confused as to what is going on. What is the best way to check

in sql server

Created a constraint, but now forgot where it was

Comment: Check your source control software, that'll tell you.

Comment: Do you mean you know the name but forgot the table, or you know the table but forgot the name?

Comment: First of all, i do not have source control. Secondly i think i can sys table to know when the constraint was added

Comment: Details of check constraints aren't in the `sys.tables` objects, they're (unsurprisingly) in `sys.check_constraints`.

Comment: If you develop software you should have source control. It's not the 60s anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good [article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/07/sql-server-ssms-schema-change-history-report/) by Pinal Dave that would solve your problem.

If *default trace* is enabled on your Sql Server,You just need to:

1. Connect your SQL Server in SSMS.
2. Right click on Server -> Reports -> Standard reports -> Schema Change history.
3. Identify your table and constrain from report.

Refer to this [article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/07/sql-server-ssms-schema-change-history-report/) for more details.